# Tomcat sends 403 at DELETE request although readonly is false

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-403, http-delete

I've got a Servlet that implements the doDelete method.

When I run the application on my tomcat (8.0.0 RC1) I get a 403 response. I checked the documentation regarding this (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/default-servlet.html) but no change.

My Servlet:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/api/binding/*",
     initParams = {
                    @WebInitParam(name="readonly", value="false")
                 })
public class BindingServlet extends BasicServlet {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BindingServlet.class);

    @Override
    protected void doDelete(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws    ServletException {
        String request = this.getRawRequest(req);

  // some code
    }
}
```

I followd the servlet implemenation through annotations from this page: http://blog.caucho.com/2009/10/06/servlet-30-tutorial-weblistener-webservlet-webfilter-and-webinitparam/

Comment: Check whether tomcat supports PUT and DELETE out of the box. It might require additional configuration.

Comment: What is `BasicServlet`?

Comment: @Sotirios: BasicServlet is just another class that does things like write the response.

Comment: @Gerald I meant what is its parent class type? `HttpServlet` or other? `HttpServlet` supports `doDelete()`.

Comment: @Kayaman: the tomcat doc says that it supports PUT and DELETE (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/funcspecs/fs-default.html) However the part "If modifications to the static resources are not allowed (set by a configuration parameter), return HTTP status 403 (forbidden)." is very cryptic as I just found the init-params to disable readonly.

Comment: @Sotirios: it extends HttpsServlet (javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet)

Comment: Are you sure you are calling an URL accomplishing the right mapping? It sounds to me as if the URL wasn't pointing to your servlet...